# Looking for vba code that will turn off OneDrive syncing

Tags: vba, excel

Can anyone point me to code that will allow me to temporarily turn on/off the One Drive syncing of the files.

I am looking of Excel 2013 VBA or API Call.

Thanks,

Karen

Comment: Have you seen [Stop syncing a library with the OneDrive for Business app](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Stop-syncing-a-library-with-the-OneDrive-for-Business-app-A7E41F1F-3A98-4CA7-9443-F10250688330)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, I was looking for vba code to turn it off and on.  do you know if such exists?

Comment: Nothing specifically off the top of my head. The [OneDrive API](https://dev.onedrive.com/) is geared toward .Net, C# and XLAM.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveWorkbook.AutoSaveOn = False

Comment: Did this not solve your problem? If it did could you upvote?